# fputcsv changes string into date

Tags: php, csv

I have an array with the following format.

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "20 - 30"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "asdasd"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "11 - 20"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "Test"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "20 - 30"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "Test Date"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "11 - 20"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "Hello World"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "1 - 10"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "Hi"
  }
}
```

When I try to output the array into a csv file, the value "11 - 20" appears as Nov-20, "1 - 10" appears as 01-Oct in the csv instead of a string. How do I saved it as just a string not a date?

```
$delimiter = ',';
$filename = 'csv_'.date('Y-m-d').'.csv';

$f = fopen('php://memory', 'w');
// headers
$fields = $data['headers'];
fputcsv($f, $fields, $delimiter);

foreach ($rows as $row) {
  fputcsv($f, $row, $delimiter);
}

fseek($f, 0);

header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '";');

fpassthru($f);
```

Comment: Select cells in excel and set format 'string' but not 'date'.

Comment: Is it possible to set it in code instead of setting it in the excel file?

Comment: I'm afraid that  Excell considers itself smarter than us. But maybe - i don't use it

Comment: Where does the question say anything about Excel? Open the file in a text editor, you should see that it is unchanged from the PHP.

Comment: @barmar *appears as 01-Oct*

Comment: Sorry, that's just impossible. PHP is just processing strings, there's no way it will treat that as a date unless you call a date function.

Comment: not true this is still happening! 1 a is recognised as 01:00:00 AM in the text file!